# Changing the text color of preference header

Tags: android, text, colors, header, preference

my overall theme is using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. When an item on the left side is selected, the text color turns WHITE, which is hard to see against the light background. I want to prevent this color change and keep it as black. Anyone know how to do this?

I tried changing listSelector styling, but that only changes the background color. I need to change the foreground text color. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_settings</item>`

That should solve the problem. The drawable that it is referencing is a selector in this case